# ios removeAllAnimations not working

Tags: ios, animation

I have an forever animation, but I want to stop it at some point I tried removeAllAnimations but it did not work.
Here is my code.

```
[self.backgroundImageView.layer removeAllAnimations];

-(void)animateToLeft{
    if(isInCenter){
        [UIView animateWithDuration:10.0f animations:^{
            backgroundImageView.frame = CGRectMake(kLeftX, 0, kBackgroundWidth, kBackgroundHeight);
        }completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            [self animateToRight];
        }];
         isInCenter = NO;
    }
    else{
        [UIView animateWithDuration:20.0f animations:^{
            backgroundImageView.frame = CGRectMake(kLeftX, 0, kBackgroundWidth, kBackgroundHeight);
        }completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            [self animateToRight];
        }];
    }

}

-(void)animateToRight{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:20.0f animations:^{
        backgroundImageView.frame = CGRectMake(kRightX, 0, kBackgroundWidth, kBackgroundHeight);
    }completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [self animateToLeft];
    }];
}
```

Comment: Use finished parameter (which tells you if animation was finished or removed) in completion handler: if (finished) [self animateToRight]; and if (finished)  [self animateToLeft];.

Answer (score 1):

> This will not work in your situation.

Because `[self.backgroundImageView.layer removeAllAnimations];` this will remove all layer animation which already have added by `[self.backgroundImageView.layer addAnimation:/*CABasicAnimation should added here*/];`

You can stop this cycle by set boolean variable in completion, then check with boolean variable.

Comment: Then what would be the solution?

Comment: @PiyushDubey He can set boolean value in completion, then check with boolean variable and `can stop this cycle.`

Comment: @Mani I guess you should add this in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use a boolean value and if that is set, don't do the next animation -- also cancel pending ones..

e.g.

```
@interface MyClass () {
     BOOL cancelAll;
}

@implementation MyClass

-(void)cancelAnimation {
     self.imageView.layer removeAllAnimations]; //!
     cancelAll = YES;
}

-(void)animateToLeft{
        if(cancelAll)
            return;
        ...
}

-(void)animateToRight{
        if(cancelAll)
            return;
        ...
}
```

Comment: written inline but the gist is: cancel using a bool as well as cancel using removeAllAnimations

Comment: yeah exactly what I just did.